# I cannot get my 3 DOF bicycle model to work

Tags: python, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a vehicle using a dynamic bicycle model but I cannot seem to get it working. If I set a constant steering angle the lateral velocity grows exponentially and creates impossible results.

```
a = 0.34284
b = 0.40716
m = 155
I = 37.29

def f_DynBkMdl(x, y, delta, theta, dt, states):
    dtheta = states[0]
    vlat = states[1]
    vlon = states[2]

    if delta > math.radians(180):
        delta = delta - math.radians(360)

    if delta<0:
        j = 1
    else:
        j = 0
    if dtheta<0:
        q = 1
    else:
        q = 0

    dtheta = abs(dtheta)
    delta = abs(delta)

    sf = delta - (a*dtheta)/vlon
    ff = 30.77*math.degrees(sf)
    pf = 0

    sr = (b*dtheta)/vlon
    fr = 30.77*math.degrees(sr)       
    pr = 0

    if j == 1:
        fr = -fr
        ff = -ff
    if q == 1:
        dtheta = -dtheta

    theta = theta%math.radians(360)

    ddtheta = (a*pf*delta + a*ff - b*fr)/I
    dvlat = (pf*delta + ff + fr)/m - vlon*dtheta
    dvlon = (pf + pr - ff*delta)/m - vlat*dtheta

    dx = -vlat*np.sin(theta) + vlon*np.cos(theta)
    dy = vlat*np.cos(theta) + vlon*np.sin(theta)

    theta = theta + dtheta*dt + (1/2)*ddtheta*dt**2
    dtheta = dtheta + ddtheta*dt
    vlat = vlat + dvlat*dt
    vlon = vlon + dvlon*dt
    vabs = np.sqrt(vlat**2 + vlon**2)
    x = x + dx*dt
    y = y + dy*dt

    states = [dtheta, vlat, vlon]

    array = np.array([x, y, theta, vabs, states])
    return array
```

With `a` and `b` being the distance between the front and rear axle to the vehicle's centre of gravity, `m` being the mass and `I` the inertia. `x` and `y` are the global position and `theta` is the heading with `delta` being the steering angle. I got these equations from this [document](https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/36615/Chapter2a.pdf). Please note I used a simplified tyre model to calculate the lateral forces and I assumed infinite friction so the friction circle was not needed.

Is there something I am missing to make this work?

Comment: Can you please check the link, it's not working for me.

Comment: https://vtechworks.lib.vt.edu/bitstream/handle/10919/36615/Chapter2a.pdf  - This link should be working

Comment: Can you please also give us a hint which equation of the document you refer to?

Comment: I used the equations of motion under heading 2.3.1 and the slip angles are taken from 2.3.2 and 2.3.3